# window.open avoid pop-up blocker from function handler

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics external link tracking code:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {

    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
            function () {
                window.open ( url, "_blank" );
                //document.location = url;
            }
        });
    }
```

which is called from:

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;" href="http://www.example.com">Full Brochure</a>
```

However, because the window.open is not called direct from the user interaction the browser pop-up blocker is engaged.

How can I achieve this so that the target is a new tab but the pop-up blocker is not engaged? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this unobtrusively. So:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" rel="external">...</a>
```

Then JS:

```
/* Find all external links in the document... */
var ext_links = document.querySelectorAll('a[rel=external]');

/* Iterate through each external link in the document... */
[].forEach.call(ext_links ,function(a){
    /* For each external link, assign an onclick callback: */
    a.addEventListener('click',function(){
        /* Google tracking code here, try this: */
        var url = a.href;
        ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url);
    })
});
```

Notice I am not using event.preventDefault() to cancel the default action of the hyperlink, so it should still open in a new window/tab, immediately after the 'click' function has run.